# Deattach app when receiving data from other apps

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I read receiving data from from other apps:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

I replace android.intent.action.SEND by android.intent.action.VIEW

But my app not split with file manager when long press home button as Walkman.

I need to handle a Walkman. Please help me.

Walkman
http://i1267.photobucket.com/albums/jj541/vannam28071988/android/Screenshot_2014-04-01-15-49-28_zps8256d10f.png

When run background my app not split with file manager as using Walkman.

This is my code snippet:

```
        Intent externalIntent = getIntent(); String action = externalIntent.getAction();
        String type = externalIntent.getType();
        Uri sendUri = externalIntent.getData(); Toast.makeText(this, "Type: " + type, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, sendUri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        String sendType = Util.AUDIO; if (type.startsWith("video")) { sendType = Util.VIDEO; }
        mainIntent.putExtra("path", sendUri.getPath()); mainIntent.putExtra("type", sendType);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to add your app in the suggested list when an audio file is clicked ?

Comment: http://i1267.photobucket.com/albums/jj541/vannam28071988/android/Screenshot_2014-04-01-15-49-02_zpsa43ccee9.png

Comment: can you post the code that you have used ?

Comment: Remove the last line "finish();".. because it close the activity that you have newly created.. and Re-run the app .. What is the error/output you're getting when you run the code ?

Comment: when your application receives data from other applications (following Google's instructions) then your application inseparable file manager

Comment: I have already removed finish(), but my problem don't solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File(YOUR_SONG_URI);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I know about your code. But It don't solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: I use mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) then it solve my problem.

Comment: That's great. Please do post your answer and accept it. So it could help others as well